# Cannot connect to localhost from mobile device using flask on Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, flask, anaconda, spyder

I've written the most basic server using Flask on Spyder (anaconda)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=False)
```

I ran it on my PC and was able to connect to it from Chrome and get the 'Hello world' message, however, when I try to connect to the url `<my-ipv4-address>`:8000 from the Chrome app on my device, I get a timeout.
The same exact code, when run from a "normal" Python editor, Sublime Text3, works perfectly. Using Python 2.7, PC, Nexus 5x.
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you open port 8000 in your firewall on your PC?

Comment: @Suever That did the trick, however, it seems a bit dangerous. Is there a better solution?

Comment: How else do you expect to access port 8000 if it isn't open? The production way to do this is to run your flask app behind a web server which proxies all requests to your app.